# Create CSR with 256 SANs

Tags: ssl, csr, certutil

Have 256 iDRACs that have never had an SSL cert.

First I tried using a power-shell script to have the iDRACS themselves create the CSR individually,

Issue with that is, older versions of iDRAC will not create Subject Alternate Name for the certs. So Chrome gives an error.

Then had the idea to add all the DRAC host names to a CSR as Subject Alternate Names.

Know how to create the CSR using the MMC snap in, but adding 256 host names manually... So looking for some way that can add them from a text file as it creates the CSR?

Hope that's clearer?

Comment: Please post what you have done so far.

Comment: Have you considered a wildcard cert?  Otherwise look to certreq and certutil.